# use spring boot embeded server only for local test

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am working on a Spring boot application with java 11. On local testing I am using embeded server provided by spring boot (undertow), but for qualifacation and production environnements the app is deployed on WAS server.

However when I checked the generated WAR, I observed that all embeded server's depenedencies are included while It is used only for local tests.

Is there a way to include undertow dependencies exclusively for local testing ?

Thank you

pom.xml

```
       <!-- undertow Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How to do that is explained in the reference guide [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.traditional-deployment.war). It is explained for tomcat but it works the same for Undertow. Note that it still will be there but in a separate directory unreachable for WAS.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did that but now I cannot run my application on local with Intellij. It is possible to download jars and tell Intellil to include them when running app ?

Comment: Check the run configuration and select the include provided dependencies.